# DotNetZip read archive from stream

Tags: c#, zip, dotnetzip

I am using `DotNetZip` library and I want to do the following steps:

1 Add same files into `ZipFile` object

2 Save the archive into `MemoryMappedViewStream` stream

3 Read archive parts from stream and save them (individually) on the HDD

The following code add files in archive and save archive on `MemoryMappedViewStream` object

```
var zip = new ZipFile();
        int SegmentsCreated = 0;
        var archieveVolumSize = 600 * 1024; // 600k segments
        zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = archieveVolumSize;
        long maximumSize = 0;
        foreach (var file in df.GetFiles().Take(5))
        {
            zip.AddFile(file.Name);
        }
        zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestSpeed;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        zip.Save(ms);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        ms.Flush();
        SegmentsCreated = zip.NumberOfSegmentsForMostRecentSave;
        zip.Dispose();
        var achieveLength = ms.Length;
        MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("ArhiveZip", ms.Length);
        MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream();
        stream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();
        ms.Close();
        ms.Dispose();
```

Before to save the archive in a Stream object I saved it on HDD and I could extract files from it.

With the following code I tried to save individually volume archive on HDD

```
stream = mmf.CreateViewStream();
        var iterations = Math.Ceiling(achieveLength * 1.0 / archieveVolumSize);
        long positionStart = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[archieveVolumSize];
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, archieveVolumSize);
            File.WriteAllBytes("ZipArhive.z0" + (i), bytes);
            positionStart += archieveVolumSize;
        }

        var archiveBytes = new byte[achieveLength - positionStart];
        stream.Read(archiveBytes, 0, archiveBytes.Length);
        File.WriteAllBytes("ZipArhive.zip", archiveBytes);
        stream.Dispose();
        mmf.Dispose();
```

The problem is that after I saved individually volume I cannot extract files from the resulted archive.

I had no exception on runtime but if I click Extract here (using WinRar program) it doesn't do anything.

Thank you in advance